# Magento displays errors in server after upgrade

Tags: magento, upgrade, magento-1.4, magento-1.7

I upgraded my magento site .the upgrading completed without errors.

But when i loading site in browser i got duplicate entry errors ,So i clear the database and again take the url in browser.But now i got this error:

```
Mage_Eav_Exception Object
(
    [_messages:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [message:protected] => Maximum length of attribute code must be less then 30 symbols
    [string:Exception:private] => 
    [code:protected] => 0
    [file:protected] => /var/www/magento_upgrade/app/Mage.php
    [line:protected] => 579
    [trace:Exception:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /var/www/magento_upgrade/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute.php
                    [line] => 158
                    [function] => exception
                    [class] => Mage
                    [type] => ::
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Mage_Eav
                            [1] => Maximum length of attribute code must be less then 30 symbols
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /var/www/magento_upgrade/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php
                    [line] => 316
                    [function] => _beforeSave
                    [class] => Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /var/www/magento_upgrade/app/code/community/Biebersdorf/CustomerOrderComment/sql/customerordercomment_setup/mysql4-install-0.0.3.php
                    [line] => 49
                    [function] => save
                    [class] => Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /var/www/magento_upgrade/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php
                    [line] => 624
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => /var/www/magento_upgrade/app/code/community/Biebersdorf/CustomerOrderComment/sql/customerordercomment_setup/mysql4-install-0.0.3.php
                        )

                    [function] => include
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /var/www/magento_upgrade/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php
                    [line] => 421
                    [function] => _modifyResourceDb
                    [class] => Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => install
                            [1] => 
                            [2] => 0.1.3
                        )

                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /var/www/magento_upgrade/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php
                    [line] => 327
                    [function] => _installResourceDb
                    [class] => Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 0.1.3
                        )

                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /var/www/magento_upgrade/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php
                    [line] => 235
                    [function] => applyUpdates
                    [class] => Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [7] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /var/www/magento_upgrade/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php
                    [line] => 417
                    [function] => applyAllUpdates
                    [class] => Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup
                    [type] => ::
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [8] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /var/www/magento_upgrade/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php
                    [line] => 343
                    [function] => _initModules
                    [class] => Mage_Core_Model_App
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [9] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /var/www/magento_upgrade/app/Mage.php
                    [line] => 683
                    [function] => run
                    [class] => Mage_Core_Model_App
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [scope_code] => 
                                    [scope_type] => store
                                    [options] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

            [10] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /var/www/magento_upgrade/index.php
                    [line] => 87
                    [function] => run
                    [class] => Mage
                    [type] => ::
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                            [1] => store
                        )

                )

        )

    [previous:Exception:private] => 
)
```

How can i solve this?
Or what i do here?

Answer (score 2):

somewhere between the actual version of your Magento install and the one you're trying to upgrade to, Magento put a limit to the characters of the sku of the EAV attributes.
The error you have is because one of your attribute have more then 30 characters in his SKU.

One thing you can do is to override Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute::ATTRIBUTE_CODE_MAX_LENGTH and make it big enough so that the upgrade go on.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

And for clarity, the full path to the file you want to edit is...

> your-project/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute.php CONST
>   ATTRIBUTE_CODE_MAX_LENGTH = 30;
>
> put the CONST ATTRIBUTE_CODE_MAX_LENGTH = 30; to 60

Stolen from: [Bijal Bhavsar](http://blog.magecracker.com/to-resolve-maximum-length-of-attribute-code-must-be-less-then-30-symbols-error-in-magento-1-6-above-version/)